# How to prevent StackOverflowError in minesweeper program?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I made a program designed to run like the game Minesweeper.  It is set up as a GridLayout and there is a recursive code called getNumberSmall in the main code, that runs when a button is clicked.  It doesn't run recursively unless the button clicked was a blank space (i.e. if you have ever played minesweeper neither a mine or a number).  When a BLANK space is clicked the code is supposed to recursively run itself on the buttons surrounding the blank button that was clicked.  HOwever, when I do it I get a stack overflow error.  How should I fix this?

```
public void getNumberSmall(JButton b3){
    JButton above = new JButton();
    JButton below = new JButton();
    JButton right = new JButton();
    JButton left = new JButton();
    JButton DRight = new JButton();
    JButton DLeft = new JButton();
    JButton DRightD = new JButton();
    JButton DLeftD = new JButton();
    JButton clicked = b3;
    int myX = (int) clicked.getClientProperty("column");
    int myY = (int) clicked.getClientProperty("row");
    int mNum = 0;

    if(myX < 9){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") - 1 == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") == myY){
                    right = small.get(i);
                    if((int)right.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        right = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        right = null;
    }

    if(myX > 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") + 1 == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") == myY){
                    left = small.get(i);
                    if((int)left.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        left = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        left = null;
    }

    if(myY < 9){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") - 1 == myY){
                    below = small.get(i);
                    if((int)below.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        below = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        below = null;
    }

    if(myY > 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") + 1 == myY){
                    above = small.get(i);
                    if((int)above.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        above = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        above = null;
    }

    if(myY == 9){
        DRightD = null;
        DLeftD = null;
    }
    if(myY == 1){
        DRight = null;
        DLeft = null;
    }
    if(myX == 9){
        DRightD = null;
        DRight = null;
    }
    if(myX == 1){
        DLeftD = null;
        DLeft = null;
    }
    if(DRight != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") - 1 == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") + 1 == myY){
                    DRight = small.get(i);
                    if((int)DRight.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        DRight = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if(DLeft != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") + 1 == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") + 1 == myY){
                    DLeft = small.get(i);
                    if((int)DLeft.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        DLeft = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if(DRightD != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") - 1 == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") - 1 == myY){
                    DRightD = small.get(i);
                    if((int)DRightD.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        DRightD = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if(DLeftD != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < small.size(); i++){
            if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("column") + 1 == myX){
                if((int) small.get(i).getClientProperty("row") - 1 == myY){
                    DLeftD = small.get(i);
                    if((int)DLeftD.getClientProperty("enabled") == 1){
                        DLeftD = null;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if(above != null){
        if((int) above.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(below != null){
        if((int) below.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(right != null){
        if((int) right.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(left != null){
        if((int) left.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(DRight != null){
        if((int) DRight.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(DLeft != null){
        if((int) DLeft.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(DRightD != null){
        if((int) DRightD.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(DLeftD != null){
        if((int) DLeftD.getClientProperty("mines") == 1){
            mNum = mNum + 1;
        }
    }

    if(mNum == 0){
        String num2 = "" + mNum;
        clicked.setText(num2);

        if((above != null) && ((int)above.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(above);
        above.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);
        }

        if((below != null) && ((int)below.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(below);
        below.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);
        }

        if((right != null) && ((int)right.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(right);
        right.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);
        }

        if((left != null )  && ((int)left.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(left);
        left.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);

        }

        if((DRight != null)  && ((int)DRight.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(DRight);
        DRight.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);

        }

        if((DLeft != null)  && ((int)DLeft.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(DLeft);
        DLeft.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);

        }

        if((DRightD != null)  && ((int)DRightD.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(DRightD);
        DRightD.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);

        }

        if((DLeftD != null)  && ((int)DLeftD.getClientProperty("enabled") == 0)){
        getNumberSmall(DLeftD);
        DLeftD.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);

        }


    }

    else{
    String number = "" + mNum;
    clicked.setText(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running your debugger. You might be able to find out why recursion doesn't stop. But if I had to guess, it might be because you call `getNumberSmall` before `putClientProperty`.

Comment: TNT- you were right!  I switched getNumberSmall and putClientProperty (and before all of that set the clicked button as enabled) and it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be setting enabled on the clicked on button so nothing stops the recursion going in a loop.

e.g: clicked -> above -> below -> above ....

Answer (score 0):

```
getNumberSmall(above);
above.putClientProperty("enabled", 1);
```

Here, having `getNumberSmall` before `putClientProperty` will cause the program to call `getNumberSmall` to use the specified button without any changes to the button being reflected, which causes recursion to continue until the StackOverflowError is thrown. If you switch the two method calls, the specified property of the JButton will change before the button is passed as an argument, and this change will be reflected on the JButton parameter.